# Python Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, attributeerror, nonetype

I am trying to combine all files in a directory and the save the combined file into another directory.
I am using Python 3.8. 
When I run the code I get the following with a AttributeError:

```
c:\test\Upload test\Book1.xlsx
c:\test\Upload test\Book2.xlsx
c:\test\Upload test\Book3.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python/PythonDev/combine.py", line 104, in <module>
newdf.to_excel(writer,"All")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import globe
filelist = glob.glob(r'c:\test\Upload test\*.xlsx')
file1 = "*.*"
for i in  filelist:
    file2 = pd.read_excel(i)
    file2['FileName'] = i
    file1 = ['newdf']
    newdf = file1.append(file2)
    print (i)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\test\Uploaded\uploadfile.xlsx', engine= 'xlsxwriter')
newdf.to_excel(writer,"All")
writer.save()
```

Comment: sorry for the typo. question should read  "I am trying to combine all files in a directory and then save the combined file into another directory."

Comment: append doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append doesn't return anything...

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

raw_files = glob.glob(r'c:\test\Upload test\*.xlsx')

pd_files = pd.DataFrame()

for file in raw_files:
    pd_files.append(pd.read_excel(file))

pd_files.to_excel("c:\test\Uploaded\uploadfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks, that has removed the error, but the saved file (uploadfile.xlsx) is empty. So the code is reading the files and generating an empty file, but the data should be appended  to this new file.   I thought pd.files.a[[end should have taken care of that?

Comment: @user8763797: I have made few changes, lmk if that code works...