# AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, excel, pandas

There are plenty of similar questions. Here are two:

[Python Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663329/python-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-to-excel)

[AttributeError: 'Object has no attribute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789280/attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute)

I want to replace underscores with a space in the excel file column header and then save it. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

ws = r'c:/users/jpilbeam/Reverse911_1a_English_.xlsx'

# data frame from excel file 
df3 = pd.read_excel(ws, header=0) 
#remove underscores
df2 = df3.columns.str.replace("_", " ")
## save to file
df2.to_excel(df2)
```

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\pathto\Python Scripts\C19VaccinationTable.py", line 18, in <module>
    df2.to_excel(df2)
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

While debugging, I notice the script will print the `columns.str.replace()` function successfully. But, it won't write to the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df3.columns` is an index object ([`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html)), so while you replace `_` it returns an index object. Instead do this:

```
import pandas as pd

ws = r'c:/users/jpilbeam/Reverse911_1a_English_.xlsx'

# data frame from excel file 
df3 = pd.read_excel(ws, header=0) 
#remove underscores
df3.columns = df3.columns.str.replace("_", " ")
## save to file
df3.to_excel(filename)   # filename being the file name you want to save it in.
```

To see how it works, you can trace each step:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, (3,4)), columns=['a_', 'b_', 'c_', 'd_'])
>>> df
 
   a_  b_  c_  d_
0   7   3   6   7
1   2   4   7   8
2   5   8   2   9

>>> df.columns  # pd.Index object
Index(['a_', 'b_', 'c_', 'd_'], dtype='object')

>>> df2 = df.columns.str.replace('_', '')

>>> df2   # Again, pd.Index object, not DataFrame
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')

# But if we assign it back to df.columns:
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_', '')

>>> df
 
   a  b  c  d
0  7  3  6  7
1  2  4  7  8
2  5  8  2  9
```

Comment: ```df2``` isn't defined?

Comment: @Pfalbaum added some explanation, I hope it's clear now. You do not need to define df2.

Comment: I put your code verbatim and all I get is the ```NameError: 'df2' is not defined``` error?

Comment: I am sorry, it will be your file name. I will edit it. I didn't notice it.